Can a contradiction exist in the antecedent of a sequent?
Consider the following sequent.
Please note that starting from the bottom, only the relevant branches were developed (the other branches did not pose a problem).
$\dfrac{
\dfrac{
\dfrac{
\dfrac{...}{A,B,A→¬C⊢ B,C} ~~~\dfrac{A,C⊢A,B,C~~~~\textbf{A,C,¬C⊢ B,C}}
{~~A,C,A→¬C⊢B,C~~}~~~→L
}
{A,B∨C,A→¬C⊢ B,C}∨L
}
{A∧(B∨C) , A→¬C    ⊢ B,C}∧L
}
{A∧(B∨C) , A→¬C    ⊢ B∨C}∨R $
If the antecedent corresponds to a conjunction of expressions, and the consequent corresponds to a disjunction, then the top line (highlighted with bold) would give us:
$A \wedge C\wedge¬C ⊢  B \vee C$ ,
what cannot be right, as it corresponds to ($\bot \vdash B \vee C $), with $B = true$.
Hm. Does this mean that, the right way to employ sequent calculus is to stop getting rid of operators as soon as an axiom appears? In the present case, after the rule ($\vee L$), we should shout "$C⊢C$ was found!" and stop, is that correct?
But.. as a subsequent (pun intended) question, is it wrong to keep applying rules, as it was done here (since that lead, apparently, to an absurd situation) ? This would mean that the application (or not) of the rules depend on context.

This question is based on a misconception: there's no problem at all with $\perp{}\vdash B\vee C$. Indeed, we have $\perp{}\vdash X$ for every $X$.
Intuitively, you want to read "$\mathscr{A}\vdash\mathscr{B}$" as "If everything in $\mathscr{A}$ is assumed to be true, we can conclude that at least one of the things in $\mathscr{B}$ must be true." If $\perp\in\mathscr{A}$ then this is vacuously true.
The same thing occurs when phrased in terms of semantics. The expression "$\varphi\models\psi$" means "Every structure satisfying $\varphi$ also satisfies $\psi$." Taking $\varphi$ to be $\perp$, the expression "$\perp\models\psi$" means "Every structure satisfying $\perp$ satisfies $\psi$," which is vacuously true (regardless of what $\psi$ is) since no structures satisfy $\perp$ in the first place.

Only at least one? I thought $A \vdash B, C$ means that both $B$ and $C$ can be concluded given $A$.

$\Gamma\vdash\Delta$ should be interpreted to mean that if all the formulas in $\Gamma$ are true, then at least one of the formulas in $\Delta$ is true.  Only at least one.  Consider the $\lor$-elimination rule: from $\Gamma\vdash \Delta, A\lor B$ we may deduce $\Gamma\vdash\Delta, A, B$.  Another way to understand this, if you know about tableau methods, is to think of it this way: To close a branch of the tableau labeled with $\Gamma \vdash \Delta$, it is necessary and sufficient to prove all the formulas in $\Gamma$ and to disprove all the formulas in $\Delta$.

I have a digression about this that might interest you, in the middle of a longer article about sequent calculus: https://blog.plover.com/math/logic/cut-rule.html

Long comemnt
Ex falso (aka: Explosion) ia a valid logical principle (in classical logic, intuitionistic logic, and others) stating that from a contradiction, any proposition can be inferred.
It can be symbolized with: $P, \lnot P \vdash Q$, and this corresponds to your: $\bot \vdash B \lor C$.
